# Android Future Notification Not Showing

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

I want my app to notify the user daily and I am using an `AlarmManager` to implement that. However, the notifications are not showing up. Also, I do not have any errors or exceptions.

This is the part of my code that sets the AlarmManager(The repeating interval is 1000ms for testing, I will change it in the actual program):

```
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, Notify.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(this.ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000, pendingIntent);
```

This is `onReceive()` in `Notify` class, which extends `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder n=new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    n.setAutoCancel(true);
    n.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    n.setTicker("ticker");
    n.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
    n.setContentTitle("title");
    n.setContentText("text");
    Intent it=new Intent(context,ListAll.class);
    PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0, it,0);
    n.setContentIntent(pi);
    ((NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).notify(uniqueID,n.build());
  }
```

And I have the following added in my Manifest.xml:

```
   <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
   <receiver android:name=".Notify" android:process=":remote" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that your user's device will need to NOT reboot at all or else your alarm will go away unless they re-launch your app, and your app knows to set the alarm again.

Documentation found:

> By default, all alarms are canceled when a device shuts down. To
>   prevent this from happening, you can design your application to
>   automatically restart a repeating alarm if the user reboots the
>   device. This ensures that the AlarmManager will continue doing its
>   task without the user needing to manually restart the alarm.

from the http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html page

---

You are setting the alarm to fire [every 1 second](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) That might be the issue, I wouldn't be surprised if the internal code would just throw away alarms like that. (for sanity of the device+ battery)

---

from the examples here: http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html#set 
You are missing lines like this, which you set 'what time' the alarm should go off.

the 'time' from `calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());` has already passed when you tell the alarm manager to set a repeating alarm. Therefore I'm not sure the behavior it will give you, but its probably your undesired behavior that you are receiving. Try to tell the alarm to 'go off' in 5 minutes, and to repeat every 20 minutes. (like the example in the guide). See if that helps.

```
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
```

---

I think you are conflating AlarmManager with AlarmClock.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

and

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/AlarmClock.html

---

I don't think you need `<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>` at all, since you aren't writing an alarm clock app. you just want to 'use' alarms.

[This guide](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) Should help you tiny up your code. Because you will need to set a broadcast receiver to be notified on [android.permission.RECIEVE_BOOT_COMPLETED](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html#boot) and this has code on how to do that. (to 'restart' your alarms each time the phone reboots)

Comment: I appreciate your help very much. I did what you suggested above, I changed it to go off every fifteen minutes, but the notifications are still not showing.

Comment: I realized I put the receiver tag outside of the application tag, that was why it didn't work. But thanks for your answer.